# Make Flippy links available in page.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

Using the [Flippy Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flippy) I would like to make the links that it prints in its theme file available in **page.html.twig** because I want to print them in a different region from where the node content gets printed.

The module states: "*If you turn on Flippy for a content type, but hide the pager in the Manage Display page, its links will still be available in the theme layer when it comes time to output node.tpl.php*"

That's correct, using Devel Module [enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) I used `dpm(content)` on my `node.html.twig`template.

[image]

Doing `{{ content.flippy_pager}}` allows me to print the links, but it's all **within** `node.html.twig`.

How could I possible pass that information on to `page.html.twig` since my goal is to print it in a different region from where the node's main content gets printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize the module provides a "Flippy" block.

- Remove "Pager" from `Structure>Content types>MyContentType>Manage display`
- Add block in `Structure>Block layout`. Go to the region you want the links to appear, click `Place block`, search for **Flippy Bock** and you are done.

ps: the answer came from stackoverflow, but I reposted it here just in case it's useful for others too.